# HTML layout question?

Tags: html

I was just wondering I'm trying to display all a members friend requests in their own form for example, three friend requests will be displayed in three different forms or 20 friend requests will be displayed in 20 different forms and so on. The reason for this is because I want each friend request to have its own `Add Friend` or `Deny Friend` button.

**So my question is:** Is this a good way to display friend requests or is there a better way using HTML or PHP & MySQL?

Here is a code sample.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <h3>Someone wants to be your friend!</h3>
                <a href=""><img src="./images/avatar.png" /></a>
                <input type="submit" name="add_friend" value="Add Friend" />
                <input type="submit" name="deny_friend" value="Deny Friend" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>

    <li>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <h3>Someone wants to be your friend!</h3>
                <a href=""><img src="./images/avatar.png" /></a>
                <input type="submit" name="add_friend" value="Add Friend" />
                <input type="submit" name="deny_friend" value="Deny Friend" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>

    <li>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <h3>Someone wants to be your friend!</h3>
                <a href=""><img src="./images/avatar.png" /></a>
                <input type="submit" name="add_friend" value="Add Friend" />
                <input type="submit" name="deny_friend" value="Deny Friend" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you asking if this is really an HTML, PHP & MySQL question or why is this question mark in the title?

Comment: Corrected the tags. Has nothing to do with PHP, especially not MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok that way. It's clean. All you need to have is some sort of an ID of the friend request, to know what operation to do server-side, regardless of server-side language.

Comment: Where should I put the ID at?

Comment: You can use <input type="hidden" value="2496258" name="request_id"/>
It won't be visible to the user, but passed with the form, so you can access it via $_POST superglobal.
That's a bit simple from the Security point of view, but it will do for now. Mosts sites don't bother securing forms.

Comment: but what if i want my form secure?

Comment: Well the protection you might need is protection from robots (unlikely, but in case you will need something like this, ReCaptcha will help), and protection from CSRF. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery . You can search discussions here for that, and if you don't find any, ask a separate question.

Comment: Do I need to put a hidden field under both the Add Friend and Deny Friend buttons?

Comment: No, you don't need. One field for the ID, and if needed - one for the security verification key for CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play it safe (i.e. have something that works without JavaScript) using multiple forms is usually the way to go. If you can rely on JavaScript, you can use with "naked" form elements and submit them through AJAX.

However, in this case,  there's no need for POST and forms. You're much better off using simple GET requests:

```
 <h3>Someone wants to be your friend!</h3>
 <a href="/friends/?command=add&id=1234567">Add friend</a>
 <a href="/friends/?command=deny&id=1234567">Denyfriend</a>
```

Comment: No, you're not better off. Using `GET` should never cause a state change, it should always be safe to re-issue a GET request at any time and as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ID value as a hidden field in the form, that way your server-side logic will be able to get that parameter and add/deny the appropriate friend.

However, I agree with Unicron -- GET requests would probably be easier (just include the parameters in the URL) unless you need to hide the ID field for security reasons.

Comment: Anyway hidden fields are only hidden in HTML, but an advanced user can easily find it out, so it's more an aesthetic issue in this case.